# Не отображается блок "Закрепить изображение" к записи

Tags: wordpress

Пожалуйста, подскажите. Направьте. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Со своей самодельной темой даже не предлагает этот блок. Для этого специальная функция нужна?
Понимаю глупый вопрос, но очень попрошу перед "-", сначала указать в какую сторону смотреть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В functions.php вашей темы добавьте

```
function mytheme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_setup' );
```

А вообще, начинать с создания своей темы неправильно. Берите из репозитория любую, делайте от неё дочернюю. Так избежите подобных проблем.